# Hyperlink to certain mail message

Tags: email, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I want to be able to create a hyperlink to a certain email message. My client i thunderbird.

I found this script https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/thunderbird/addon/thunderlink/?src=userprofile

and after installing it as well as adding the code

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thunderlink]
@="URL:thunderlink Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thunderlink\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thunderlink\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\thunderlink\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Thunderbird\\thunderbird.exe\" -thunderlink \"%1\""
```

to a file called

> scriptet-som-behovs.reg

in my folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird

and then double clicking it...

the program just does not work. **I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.** Maybe someone know why it does not work, or have another solution